# Pointing a domain to a public google apps script

Tags: google-apps-script, dns, web-hosting

I have a domain registered in www.namecheap.com website, also I developed a website using google apps script which is publicly available. How can I point my domain name to that google app script link and use it as my website home page? Thanx in advance.

Comment: you can redirect to the script, but I doubt you can map it directly.

Answer (score 0):

Try attaching the script to a Google site. Then you can map your naked domain to the sites.google.com site.